# search box changes when I put it on my blog

Tags: html, css, search-box

can you please tell me what's wrong in this code? it looks fine in here, but once I add it to my blog it changes

[image]

thank you very much

```html
<style>
  #rectangle {
    width: 245px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #F8E7E1;
    padding: 40px;
  }
  .container-1 input#search {
    border: 0.5px solid #ccc;
    width: 240px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: left;
    color: #000;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
</style>

<div id="rectangle">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="container-1">
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
      <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It most definitely is a box-sizing issue.
`box-sizing: border-box;` sounds to be what you need.

Comment: where should I add it?

Comment: It's either on the #rectangle or something above it